# Setting up Android Studio and/or SDK for dual boot

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to ask if anyone installed one Android Studio and/or SDK for multiple OS. Now I have Win and Ubuntu dual boot and wondering, if there's a way to have single installation of Android Studio and/or Android SDK to save drive space and manage udpates at once for both platforms?

Thanks in advance
Ales

Comment: No... but, if you can access the code from the other disk partition, Android Studio will open it. Try to use a git based website to make the commits. Is the best way to keep your code updated trough different computers/OS/etc

Comment: IMHO, the question rather belongs to the scope of SuperUser than StackOverflow. Please consider asking there.